# Is Prismite considered colorless or all colors for the purpose of Brawl/Commander decks?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-color-identity

Me and the person I'm playing with were making [Brawl](https://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/formats/brawl) decks. And we got into an argument about if [Prismite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPrismite%5d) was colorless or all colors. So which is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's colorless:

> 903.4. The Commander variant uses color identity to determine what cards can be in a deck with a certain commander. The color identity of a card is the color or colors of any mana symbols in that card’s mana cost or rules text, plus any colors defined by its characteristic-defining abilities (see rule 604.3) or color indicator (see rule 204).

Prismite's ability says: "{2}: Add one mana of any color." and not "{2}: Add {W}, {U}, {B}, {R} or {G}." No mana symbols appear in the rules text, so it's colorless.

Note that Brawl uses the same definition of 'color identity' as Commander:

> 903.11a Brawl is an option for a different style of Commander game. Brawl games use the normal rules for the Commander variant with the following modifications.